# C#, Properties using strings

Tags: c#, wpf, string

C#, Visual studio 2010, Windows 7

When you set the image to WPF control image you can specifify the source to the image like this

```
/MyTest;component/images/Misc/bg.jpg
```

But how do you do with strings, I have a number of strings resources, for example, 
strings.resx, strings.sv-Se.resx etc. and want to use this "string concept" when 
specify the text to a button.

What should I write in the properties (or the XAML file for the window) to retrive the strings?

I have tried

```
/MyTest;component/strings.File
```

me:`strings.File`

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve (Localization?), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665764/how-to-fetch-string-from-resource-to-assign-in-wpf-resource-section-in-xaml) maybe what you're looking for or this question is even a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the access specifier of resx file be `public`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Static prop:Resources.String1}"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

refrence : Accessing strings from [resx file](http://gargmanoj.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/accessing-strings-from-resource-file-in-xaml-markup/)

Comment: Hi

Thanks a lot, that did the trick, your suggestion also led me to this site

http://gargmanoj.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/accessing-strings-from-resource-file-in-xaml-markup/

Regards