# Rename a button with < character in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application in which I try to rename a button like that `<<  Précédent`

```
<Button Content="Suivant >>" Background="#FFF9F7F7" Margin="0,0,100,8"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" BorderBrush="CadetBlue"  BorderThickness="2" />
<Button Content="<< Précédent" Background="White" Margin="0,0,180,8"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        BorderBrush="CadetBlue"  BorderThickness="2" />
```

But an error appears in the second button name

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. How can i fix it?

Comment: "an error occurs" gives us very little information...

Comment: You should note that `>>` and `»` and `<<` and `«` are different characters - especially since `>>` and `<<` are really two characters, while the others are a single character. If you want to use `>>`, go with Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: This looks like french to me (right?). IMO, with all UI elements in production code, you should globalise (prepare for translation) all strings using a `resx` file and the `{x:Static}` mark up extension. As a bonus, you no longer have to use the escape sequences. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2170357/286976

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect this is just a matter of XML escaping for `<`, as you can't use `<` directly within an attribute value. Try:

```
<Button Content="&lt;&lt; Précédent" ...>
```

... and please provide more details in your next question.

(You'd need the same escaping for XML content too, as otherwise it will be treated as the start of a new element.)

Comment: as an expansion to the answer, `>` is `&gt;` (greater than)

Comment: @Gusdor: Indeed, although that's not necessary in nearly as many cases.